# Casting uint8 to uint32

Tags: c, embedded, xilinx

I am having some trouble casting uint8 and uin32 in embedded C. Here is the code I am using...

```
int b = 0;
u8 dt[4] = {0};
while (there_is_buffer(rbuf)) {
    dt[b] = (u8)(popFront(rbuf));
    if (b > 2) {
        uint32_t _Recv = (uint32_t)dt;

        /*      xil_printf("data: %x%x%x%x\n\r",dt[3], dt[2], dt[1], dt[0]);  */
        xil_printf("data: %x\n\r", _Recv);
        b = 0;
    }
    else  
        b++;
}
```

The printf statement that is commented out works fine, but the other one doesn't. What am I doing wrong in here? How can I cast the `u8` array to uint32?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `dt` is a pointer so when you cast it to `uint32_t` you just take its address as the value that will be stored in `_Recv`.

You should try casting it to a `uint32_t` and then dereference it:

```
uint32_t _Recv = *((uint32_t*)dt)
```

so that the address will be interpreted as a pointer to an `unsigned int`.

A more readable approach would be to build the value with shifts:

```
uint32_t _Recv = dt[3]<<24 | dt[2]<<16 | dt[1]<<8 | dt[0];
```

This will also allow you to manage endianness as you wish.

Comment: The `*((uint32_t*)dt)` is endian independent unlike the `dt[3]<<24 | dt[2]<<16 ...` method (as you mentioned).   But the first is subject to alignment access problems.  The 2nd depends on sizeof(int) >= 4.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way using `memcpy` and is machine independent.

```
memcpy (&_Recv,&dt[0],4);
_Recv=htons(_Recv);
```

This way you can have an array of uint8 and cast any 4 bytes to uint32